# how to use GroupBy clause in doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

How to convert the following query into doctrine2 query

```
with using method createQuery() or createQueryBuilder()

select customer,sum(marks) from BlogBundle:Customers group by customer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb->select('customer', 'SUM(marks)')->from('BlogBundle:Customers', 'customer')->groupBy('customer.id');
```

Comment: $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('tra.customer', 'SUM(tra.points)')
           ->from('AdminBundle:Transactions', 'tra')
           ->groupBy('tra.customer');
        $points = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();                                         This is my real example, when excuting this code getting the following error                                                                      [Semantical Error] line 0, col 11 near 'customer, SUM(tra.points)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.    Please help to fix this

Comment: you should `->leftJoin('tra.points', 'points')->addSelect('SUM(points.id)');`